# Tracking subscribers who cast to AppleTV or Chromecast

Tags: streaming, chromecast, apple-tv

Is there a way to see how many sessions are cast to users’ TVs (e.g., from iPhone to Apple TV, or from Android to Chromecast)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytics solution like Google Analytics to track and count any events from your application, including CAST events.

You can see more info here about Google analytics specifically: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

A simple example, modified from one at the above link, might be:

```js
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'Cast',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```